# Does function parameter get declared as a variable since it holds a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

This code is from the Jon Duckett JS textbook.  My question is does `minLength` not require to be declared as a variable?

```
var elUsername = document.getElementById(‘username’); //get username input
var elMsg = document.getElementById(‘feedback’);      //get feedback element

function checkUsername(minLength){                    //declare function
  if(elUsername.value.length < minLength) {            //if username too short
    //set the error message
    elMsg.textContent = 'Username must be ' + minLength + ' characters or more’;
  } else {
    elMsg.innerHtml = ‘ ’;
  }

}

elUsername.addEventListener(‘blue’, function(){      //when it loses focus
  checkUsername(5);                              //pass arguments here
}, false),
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on your second line. `vr` should be `var`. You are also mixing straight-quotes with smart-quotes and this will also cause syntax errors. Use only straight quotes and make sure that your file is encoded using a well-known standard, such as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks Scot, I copied this code from the Jon Puckett textbook as it is serve for that single var typo.

Answer (score 0):

`minLength` is a named parameter to your `checkUsername` function. You do not re-declare it within that function. It acts as if you had declared a local variable and it is the responsibility of the function caller to send that value to the function.